# Getting an error of invalid identifier when try to create relationship between two tables in Oracle SQL developer?

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my device table

```
CREATE TABLE "DEVICE" (
  "IMEI_Number" varchar(15),
  "Device_Model" varchar(30),
  "Device_Description" varchar(500),
  "Assigned_Sim_Number" varchar(11),
  "Activation_Date" timestamp,
  "Deactivation_Date" timestamp,
  "Manufacturer_ID" int,
  "Customer_ID" int,
  PRIMARY KEY ("IMEI_Number")
);
```

Then I have the manufacturer table which is

```
CREATE TABLE "MANUFACTURER" (
  "Manufacturer_ID" int,
  "Manufacturer_Name" varchar(30),
  PRIMARY KEY ("Manufacturer_ID")
);
```

and I trying to create a relationship between these and getting the `ORA-00904: "MANUFACTURER_ID": invalid identifier`
My relationship code is

```
ALTER TABLE DEVICE
ADD FOREIGN KEY (Manufacturer_ID) REFERENCES MANUFACTURER(Manufacturer_ID);
```

Comment: `ALTER TABLE DEVICE
ADD FOREIGN KEY ( "Manufacturer_ID") REFERENCES MANUFACTURER( "Manufacturer_ID");` **[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6875f442561e045d2d63020279854abf)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The columns in the tables you've created are surrounded by double-quotes, making their names **case-sensitive**, while the `alter` statement does not use quotes, and thus can't match the case-sensitive column name.

The best practice would be to drop these quotes and make the column names case-insensitive. If this is not an option, you could use the same quotes in the `alter` statement too:

```sql
ALTER TABLE DEVICE
ADD FOREIGN KEY ("Manufacturer_ID") REFERENCES MANUFACTURER("Manufacturer_ID");
-- Here ---------^---------------^--------------------------^---------------^
```

Comment: Thank you so much mureinik. You save my day. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

That's just **awful**. Don't use double quotes when creating objects in Oracle as you'll have to use them **every time** you reference those objects, and match letter case **every time**.

```
SQL> alter table device add constraint fk_mf foreign key ("Manufacturer_ID")
  2  references manufacturer ("Manufacturer_ID");

Table altered.

SQL>
```

---

A better option would be

```
SQL> create table device (
  2    imei_number         varchar2(15),
  3    device_model        varchar2(30),
  4    device_description  varchar2(500),
  5    assigned_sim_number varchar2(11),
  6    activation_date     timestamp,
  7    deactivation_date   timestamp,
  8    manufacturer_id     int,
  9    customer_id         int,
 10    primary key (imei_number)
 11  );

Table created.

SQL> create table manufacturer (
  2    manufacturer_id     int,
  3    manufacturer_name   varchar2(30),
  4    primary key (manufacturer_id)
  5  );

Table created.

SQL> alter table device add constraint fk_mf foreign key (manufacturer_id)
  2    references manufacturer (manufacturer_id);

Table altered.

SQL>
```

(Note also `VARCHAR2` datatype; use that instead of `VARCHAR`).

By default, Oracle stores names in uppercase into data dictionary, but you can reference them using any case you want (upper, lower, mixed). If you do use double quotes, then you have to use their names exactly as during creation phase.

Comment: Thank you so much littlefoot. You save my day. Thanks a lot